# Oracle Linux: How to set the metric of a NIC?

Tags: networking, route, oracle-linux, metric

How can I set the metric of a network interface (DHCP) permanently in Oracle Linux (think it is managed my NetworkManager)?

Answer (score 1):

The network is managed by NetworkManager, you can use `nmcli` to set the metric:

to show connection use `nmcli c` (`nmcli connection`) , then use :

```
nmcli c edit CONNECTION_NAME
```

from the interactive mode to get the current metric use  `print`:

```
nmcli> print
```

to set a metric:

```
nmcli> set ipv4.route-metric <value>
nmcli> set ipv6.route-metric <value>
nmcli> save
nmcli> quit
```

Or you can use the following command without running the interactive mode:

```
nmcli connection modify uuid UUID_CONNECTION ipv4.route-metric <value>
nmcli connection modify uuid UUID_CONNECTION ipv6.route-metric <value>
```

Then restart NetworkManager

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

to check it:

```
route -n
```

or

```
nmcli connection show uuid UUID_CONNECTION |grep route-metric
```

Comment: Would that be permanent after a reboot?

Comment: @chris01 The NetworkManager should save the current configuration to be permanent.

Comment: @chris01 All `nmcli connection modify` commands are permanent unless you explicitly add the `--temporary` option to make a non-permanent change.

Comment: `systemctl restart NetworkManager` is almost always the wrong thing to do. NetworkManager will try *not* to apply any changes during restart, so the contrary of what the aim is here. Instead, after modifying a profile, make the changes effective by activating the profile (`nmcli connection up $NAME`). That is also the case, if the profile is currently already active, then just reactivate it (still with `nmcli con up`).